# Is there a way to create a chatbox with domino-ui components that is fixed one in right corner?

Tags: user-interface, gwt, frontend, domino-ui

i'm trying to create a chatbox with domino-ui components, a fixed one in right corner of screen like the chat you can open in the showcase of [demo app](https://dominokit.github.io/domino-ui-demo/index.html?theme=indigo#home). Does anyone know a simple way to do that? I'm searching a sort of advice on components to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking for a way to open a panel and implement your own chat dialog you can use sheet modals demonstrated here
[sheet modals](https://dominokit.github.io/domino-ui-demo/index.html?theme=indigo#components/modals)
you can open a left or right modal with 3 different sizes